# How to run css line in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to make a dynamic row counter for my table. I do this with a span but how do i run my javascript function on it so it prints the number out?

html;

```
<span id="Tellen"></span>
```

Javascript;

```
function tellen(){
    var rowCount = document.getElementById('tableID').rows.length;
}
```

Could someone help me into the right direction, much appreciated.

Comment: `document.getElementById('Tellen').innerText = rowCount;`

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_table_insertrow

Comment: document.getElementById('Tellen').textContent = rowCount;

Answer (score 2):

**You didn't assign output to html span**

Try this Tag :

```
<span id="Tellen"></span>
```

JS

```
function tellen(){
    var rowCount = document.getElementById('tableID').rows.length;
    document.getElementById('Tellen').innerText = rowCount
}
```

But you need some event to call `tellen()` .. It can be onClick of button or something like this